# Increment in Rank on encountering particular column value

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, ranking-functions

Status of a Job can progress like below throughout its journey.

ACT > AWI > ISS > EXC > COM > FUR

Sample data is as below.

| PIN | JOB_NO | DATE_TIME | JOB_STATUS | SEQ | INSERT_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 06:53:29 | ISS | 4 | 0 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 06:58:29 | EXC | 5 | 0 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:23:27 | FUR | 6 | 1 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:23:59 | ISS | 4 | 0 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:24:17 | FUR | 6 | 1 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:31:07 | ISS | 4 | 0 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:35:07 | EXC | 5 | 0 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:38:07 | COM | 6 | 0 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:40:00 | FUR | 6 | 1 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 09:04:56 | ISS | 4 | 1 |

INSERT_FLAG = 1 indicates the latest/last job data in that job progression. calculated based on the change in order of progression in status (Using SEQ)

Whenever the job resets its progression or INSERT_FLAG is 1, increment the RANK.

Note: Finally, this RANK column is used to group the progression to get the DATE_TIME for respective JOB_STATUS in that progression using Max().

Expected output.

| PIN | JOB_NO | DATE_TIME | JOB_STATUS | SEQ | INSERT_FLAG | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 06:53:29 | ISS | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 06:58:29 | EXC | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:23:27 | FUR | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:23:59 | ISS | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:24:17 | FUR | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:31:07 | ISS | 4 | 0 | 3 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:35:07 | EXC | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:38:07 | COM | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 07:40:00 | FUR | 6 | 1 | 3 |
| XYZ149 | C51341353 | 07/10/2023 09:04:56 | ISS | 4 | 1 | 4 |

I tried to use rank() with case statement inside window clause to identify the progression to increment the rank. But not working.

Comment: What's wrong with `select x.*, 1 + sum(pif) over(order by date_time) from (select t.*, lag(insert_flag) over(order by date_time) as pif) x`?

Comment: Thanks @TheImpaler. I can see the output as expected.